# How to populate a github repository with local git repository?

Tags: linux, git, github

I Have a local git repository working without problem. However, I want to send this repository to populate a new repository on github. Reading through github documentation I keep reading how to branch off a remote repository or how to push to a remote repository but not how to initially populate the remote repository. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all create a repository on github and note the url for that repository. Now moce to your local repository and add new origin. With the command .

```
git remote add origin paste/your/github/url
```

Now you can check the same with the command

```
git remote -v
```

if its reflecting or not.

Now just type command

```
 git push origin master
```

and all local repository contents are moved to your Github repository.

Answer (score 1):

On local repository:

git init

git add .

git commit -m 'First commit'

git remote add origin remote_repository_URL

git remote -v

git push origin master

Please note that remote_repository_URL is the url of your newly created github repository.

Comment: Yes, but it is safe to do git init on existing repository, just to be sure

Answer (score 0):

Once you created the repo on github, just follow their instructions, which are like:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/reponame.git
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is little unclear, but still by 'initially populate', I assume you wish to create new repository.

Please read about it here:
https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new repository on GitHub, they tell you what to do:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:your_username/your_repository_on_github.git
git push -u origin master
```